# Using primitive type parameter in OCMVerify

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, mocking, ocmock

I am using [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/) as a mocking framework in my iOS project. When I try to use OCVerify functionality to test that a certain method is invoked, I came across a problem of passing primitive types as parameters. 
Here is an example to show problem:

1-) Cases successfully verify invocation when no parameter or an object parameter.

```
OCMVerify([mockedClass methodToCall])
OCMVerify([mockedClass methodWithObjectParameter:[OCMArg any]);
```

2-) When I want to verify a method that takes an **int** as a parameter:

```
OCMVerify([mockedClass methodWithIntParameter:[OCMArg any]);
```

In this case **[OCMArg any]** doesn't act like as expected. It returns an actual integer and that causes a mismatch of parameter values. In reality I do not care if that integer value is correct or not. My only consideration is if the method is called with any integer regardless of its value.

I want to know that is there a way to have exact same effect of **[OCMArg any]** has on objects when using primitive types as parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [section 4](http://ocmock.org/reference/#argument-constraints) in the documentation.